# Changing Jxls into apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxls

I have a general question.
I don’t know it’s properly to ask here but now I change jxls into Apache poi because I need to read 
Xlsx files with images.
I’m working for a week but I can’t modify it... is that difficult to do??

Comment: Please add code snippets to support your question so that others can understand the issue properly and help you out.

Comment: Please ask a more concrete question. What exact `Jxls` code you wants changing to `apache poi` code?